# Why question about looking for geograpic dataset with specific requirements was closed as "relating to general IT or with no clear GIS component"?

Tags: discussion, scope, close-reasons

I was worried that [Is there any open waterway/lake dataset more detailed than 10m Natural Earth and less detailed than OpenStreetMap?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/389119/is-there-any-open-waterway-lake-dataset-more-detailed-than-10m-natural-earth-and) may be too subjective (that is why I tried selecting objective requirements), but why it was closed as

> relating to general IT or with no clear GIS component

? It seems to me that geographic data set has quite clear GIS component?

Answer (score 1):

I think all questions seeking open data recommendations are better asked at the [Open Data Stack Exchange](https://opendata.stackexchange.com) which has a tag for [geospatial](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geospatial) and to date 738 questions seeking open geospatial data that have been well received.  However, I do not vote to close them here, unless they are unclear, unfocused or off-topic for another reason, because a significant proportion of our community say that they think such questions are better asked here.

Consequently, I can understand the sentiment of users voting to close them, but I think the close reason used on your question is inappropriate because it clearly does have a GIS component.  If users are going to vote to close questions seeking open data recommendations then I think they should either use a close reason of Other or, if they prefer less typing, then they could propose a revised wording for the close reason they are currently using, like we did four years ago at [Improving wording of "no GIS component" custom close reason?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4356/improving-wording-of-no-gis-component-custom-close-reason)